# NSFetchedResultsController - id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo - [sectionInfo numberOfObjects] is 1 with two objects

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using this common method to get the number of objects in my section of my `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsControllerCourse sections] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSInteger sectionInfoCount = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
```

It seems to be off by one. I understand it is 1 based instead of 0, and so with three objects it should return 3.

`sectionInfoCount = 2` when there are 3 objects.
`sectionInfoCount = 1` when there are 2 objects.
`sectionInfoCount = 1` when there is 1 object.

Why does `sectionInfo` equal 1 when there are 2 OR 1 objects, and 2 when there are 3? (3, when there are 4, etc...)

It happens when casting to an int also. (I thought it might be an NSInteger wrapping issue)

Comment: For those who's found this question: see here: http://mikeabdullah.net/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html

Answer (score 0):

The `SectionInfo.numberOfObjects` will return the "count", similar to the `count` of an array. So your assumption is not correct. `(<Section info count>, <actual number of objects>)` is **always** `(n,n)`.

Check the data stored in your persistent store, your fetched results controller setup, especially the sorting and `sectionNameKeyPath` and verify that this is consistent.

Comment: Right, it should return 3 if there are 3 results. How is my assumption different? I should see a return of 2 if there are 2 objects, but I see a return of 1.

Comment: I am sure your verification of the count of objects is not correct. Show how you are verifying the count. Perhaps you have to re-fetch the FRC or implement the delegate methods.

Comment: I am verifying the count by printing it with NSLog. I have all the delegates implemented.

Comment: That's not verifying it. You need to compare the printed number it with the actual items in the database :-) Please amend your question and add your FRC code, the result you are expecting and the result you are getting.